# How to add space in legends title

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I have added legends title using highchart but i need to add 10 space in the legends title words. how to add white spaces between two words. I used padding still did not worked as I am using span. here is the code.

```
legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Name1 <span style="color:red;margin-left:2.25em; display:inline-block;"> Name2</span>',
                  style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic',
                        content: "\00a0 \00a0 "
                          } },
```

Comment: Is ` sttyle` a typo or on purpose?

Comment: copy paste problem, updated.

Comment: The HTML objects are converted into SVG, so CSS styles are ignored. The solution is using [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add custom text.

Comment: To add to what @SebastianBochan mentioned, also consider `renderer.html` if you want to add more than just basic CSS. The `renderer.text` method will convert simple HTML tags to `<span>`, which might not work well for more complex formatting.